# HTML change font-weight with javascript based on td tag conent

Tags: jquery, html, css

Sorry if this has been asked before, but I need to change my td tag content based on the value inside
Code is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Kaubamaja</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="nicer.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Store</h1>
<h3>464</h3>
<table border="0" class="dataframe">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th>AK ID</th>
      <th>Product</th>
      <th>EAN</th>
      <th>Code</th>
      <th>Bill</th>
      <th>TK</th>
      <th>XML</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>385541</td>
      <td>AeroCool PC kast mATX ilma toiteplokita Aerocool CYLON MINI RGB - 
       USB3.0 TEMPERED GLASS</td>
      <td>4718009152359</td>
      <td>AEROPGSCYLONMINI-TG</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>361334</td>
      <td>Aerocool Cylon RGB Midi-Tower - White</td>
      <td>4713105950229</td>
      <td>ACCM-PV10012.21</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

If td:nth-of-type(6) is greater than 1 it's font-weight needs to be bold.

So far i have tried jquery solution which does not work for some reason

```
$('td:nth-of-type(6):not(contains("1"))').css('font-weight:bold', 700);
```

Am I approaching it completely wrong or do not understand the process?
I have tried searching, but none of them so far has matched what I need.

Best regards,
Raidar

Comment: I have just posted my answer hope you can solve your problem with this

Comment: I must be doing something really wrong because none of these solutions work for me. Like it doesn't recognise the script.js file I have references in <head>

Comment: You are not attach jquery.js which is required to compile any jquery <script
     src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"
     integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
     crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

Comment: Unbelivable, all the options work great in JSFiddle but HTML file on my computer will not show the effect. I have added jQuery CDN and script file. What could be happening?

Comment: put your jquery code inside $(document).ready(function(){});

Comment: That did it! Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$('.dataframe td:nth-child(6)').each(function(){
   if(parseInt($(this).html())>1)
      $(this).css('font-weight','bold');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$('table.dataframe tbody tr').each(function(mind, mval) {
    if (parseInt($(mval).find('td:eq(5)').text()) > 1) {
        $(mval).find('td:eq(5)').css('font-weight', 'bold')
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You missed a colon `:` before `contains`.

Also, arguments in `css` method are incorrect. Here's the corrected snippet,

```
$('td:nth-of-type(6):not(:contains("1"))').css('font-weight', 'bold');
```

[Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/50kouaq1/2/)

Comment: I like that it is simple, but there is a small issue. It does not differentiate between 1, 10 or 100 for some reason. For example 1 and 10 both are not bold. Is there a way around it with the same solution?

Comment: In that case, the answer you accepted is the best solution.